# CrystalReport Not showing any data and no errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm using CrystalReport in my web application. I'm using VS2013. my problem is after adding  CrystalReportViewer and CrystalReportSource from tool box and wrote following code in button_click event

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
                rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/test_upload/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
                CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
                CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
            }
```

it is not showing crystalreport or any data in browser. and not showing any error. How do I solve this?

What I have tried:

Changing the code

```
protected void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string constring = "Data Source=as400_2;User Id=FADLI;Authentication=Server;Initial Catalog=S065FD45;Package Collection=FADLI;Default Schema=FADLI;Default Qualifier=FADLI;DBMS Platform=DB2MVS;";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COBKD, COBDESC FROM ASEINDTA.MSTCOB", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
adp.Fill(dt);
ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
rptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/test_upload/CrystalReport1.rpt"));
rptDoc.SetDataSource(dt);
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptDoc;
CrystalReportViewer1.DataBind();
}
```

I've tried all the solution that I've got from stackoverflow, but none of them worked. Can someone help me solving this problem?

Comment: When you run the query on DB, are you able to see data?

Comment: Yes. I can see the whole data with no error